# Python extension is not prompting to select venv

Tags: visual-studio-code

I followed this guide here, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_create-a-virtual-environment

But it's not giving me this prompt even after I've run 'python -m venv .venv' (.venv created).

Is it possible that I somehow messed up the settings? if yes how can I reset the setting only for this python extension? (I wouldn't want to reset all settings).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same  issue while using vs-code in container, I solved it by uninstalling and reinstalling extension few times